# SELECT BRING THE COLUMN MAX

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select with subselect inner join and so on. But from this result I'd like it to bring me the largest record in the OidBilling column. below is the example of select and the example of the result that it brings so that it is easier the understanding of the result that I want.

```
select address_block_uc
      ,address_complement_uc
      ,u.name_uc
      ,m.description_meter
      ,m.serial_number_meter
      ,lst.date_read date_read
      ,value_read
      ,tm.name_type_meter
      ,lst.concentrator
      ,lst.port 
      ,m.oid_uc
      ,m.oid_meter
      ,m.type_constant
      ,f.first_measur
      ,lst.id_system
      ,ib.read0
      ,ib.oid_individual_billing
      ,get_correction_factor( lst.id_system, m.oid_meter, m.oid_uc, lst.date_read) corr_factor
      ,get_correction_pulse( lst.id_system, lst.concentrator, lst.port, lst.date_read) corr_pulse
      ,nvl(f.first_measur,0) + ( i.value_read * m.type_constant ) leitura
from (select id_system
            ,concentrator
            ,port
            ,date_read
            ,m.oid_uc
            ,m.oid_meter
      from rs_individual_read i
          ,rs_uc u, rs_meter m
          ,rs_counters c
      where m.oid_meter = c.oid_meter
      and c.concentrator_counters = i.concentrator
      and c.port_counters = i.port
      and date_read between to_date ('01/03/2017 23:00:00','dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') and to_date ('25/03/2017 23:00:00','dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
      and date_read between c.dt_init and c.dt_end
      and date_read between m.dt_init and m.dt_end
      and u.oid_system=i.id_system
      and m.oid_uc=u.oid_uc
      and i.id_system=531
      and m.oid_meter=69451
      group by id_system
              ,concentrator
              ,i.port
              ,date_read
              ,m.oid_uc
              ,m.oid_meter) lst
inner join rs_individual_read i 
on (i.id_system = lst.id_system 
    and i.date_read = lst.date_read
    and i.concentrator = lst.concentrator
    and i.port = lst.port)
inner join rs_counters c
on (c.concentrator_counters = lst.concentrator
    and c.port_counters = lst.port
    and lst.date_read between c.dt_init and c.dt_end)
inner join rs_meter m
on (m.oid_meter = c.oid_meter
    and m.oid_meter = lst.oid_meter
    and lst.date_read between m.dt_init and m.dt_end)
inner join rs_uc u
on (u.oid_system = lst.id_system 
and u.oid_uc = lst.oid_uc
and u.oid_uc = m.oid_uc)
inner join rs_type_meter tm
on (m.oid_type_meter = tm.oid_type_meter)
inner join rs_individual_billing ib
on (ib.serial_number = m.serial_number_meter)
left outer join rs_first_measurs f
on (f.oid_meter = m.oid_meter)
order by date_read desc
        ,address_block_uc
        ,address_complement_uc
        ,name_uc
```

the results:

```
DATE_READ   OID_INDIVIDUAL_BILLING  LEITURA                                                                 
20/03/2017 23:00    8500    800                                                                 
20/03/2017 23:00    8791    800                                                                 
20/03/2017 23:00    8628    800                                                                 
19/03/2017 23:00    8500    450,971                                                                 
19/03/2017 23:00    8628    450,971                                                                 
19/03/2017 23:00    8791    450,971                                                                 
19/03/2017 23:00    8791    450,653                                                                 
19/03/2017 23:00    8500    450,653                                                                 
19/03/2017 23:00    8628    450,653                                                                 
19/03/2017 12:00    8628    450,653                                                                 
19/03/2017 12:00    8791    450,653
```

The result of this brings some repeated schedules in the report, and for it not to be repeated I would like the result to bring only the greater data of the column oid_individual_billing of the same date for example, in the date 19/03/2017 23: 00hs we have 3 registers however I would like that it only show line 8791 which is the largest id of the oid_individual_billing column for this record ... could anyone help me?

I've summarized the columns for easy posting.

Sorry my english from google translator

Tks!

Comment: Hi, in the 3 rows you mention from the results of the query posted above. what is the logic to keep only line 8791 (which is two if I am not mistaken) e.g. WHERE OID_INDIVIDUAL_OID = 8791???

Comment: Hello, first thank you for the response and for your interest in trying to help.
I will try to summarize the logic of wanting the line 8971, this line this id 8971 was the last one to be inserted for this date. Was I clear?

Comment: If I had a way to insert a max column by putting in the select "I want the largest oid_billing for date x" would look perfect. but I do not know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I have de answer and it works, follow below to help someone in the future

```
 inner join (select serial_number, max(read0) read0 from rs_individual_billing group by serial_number) temp
    on (temp.serial_number = m.serial_number_meter)
```

tks!